# how does the increment operator work when an expression is printed inside and when it is assigned to a variable and then it is printed

Tags: c, increment

Program 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = 10, m;

   m = a++ + ++a - a++;

   printf("%d %d", m, a);
}
```

Program 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = 10;

   printf("value of m=%d", a++ + ++a - a++);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: To be clear, it is the behavior of evaluating the expression `a++ + ++a - a++` that is undefined.  This has nothing in particular to do with the question given in the title, but we are assuming that you ask because you have observed manifestations of the undefinedness.